InvalidaragumentError in tensorflow : AddN


! InvalidArgument Error
I can't understand why this is happening.
please, help me.
I try to make big multimodal model.
First, I thought datalaoder has some problem. but I think it works well when I check it.
And even i try to use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator but It happens same problem.
The code is:
from keras.utils import Sequence
import numpy as np
import math

class multidataloader(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, label, batch_size = 32):
        self.ecg = np.load(f"data/ECG/{label}_signal.npy")
        self.emg = np.load(f"data/EMG/{label}_signal.npy")
        self.airflow = np.load(f"data/AIRFLOW/{label}_signal.npy")
        self.target = np.load(f"data/target/{label}_signal.npy")
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        """
    This class defines a multimodal neural network model that processes three input signals: ECG, EMG, and Airflow.
    Each input is processed through its respective model (ecg_model, emg_model, airflow_model), and the outputs
    are concatenated and passed through LSTM layers to make a final prediction.
    """

    def __len__(self):
        return int(math.floor(self.target.shape[0]/self.batch_size))
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if (idx+1)*self.batch_size > self.target.shape[0]:
            raise ValueError(f"Empty batch encountered at index {index}. Adjust your batch size or data.")
        batch_ecg = self.preprocessing(self.ecg, idx)
        batch_emg = self.preprocessing(self.emg, idx)
        batch_airflow = self.preprocessing(self.airflow, idx)
        batch_target = self.preprocessing(self.target, idx)


        return (batch_ecg, batch_emg, batch_airflow), batch_target
        
        
    def preprocessing(self, signal, idx):
        signal = signal[idx*self.batch_size : (idx+1)*self.batch_size]
        if signal.ndim != 1:
            signal = np.expand_dims(signal, axis = -1).astype(np.float32)
        signal = tf.convert_to_tensor(signal)
        signal = tf.cast(signal, tf.float32)
        return signal
 

with strategy.scope():datal
    train_generator = multidataloader("train")
    test_generator = multidataloader("test")
    valid_generator = multidataloader("valid")
    model = multimodal_model()
    model.compile(
        loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = True),
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
        metrics = ['accuracy']
    )
    
    for ep in range(epochs//50):
        history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 50, validation_data = valid_generator )
        for name in history.history:
            historys[name].extend(history.history[name])
            test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(generator=test_generator)
            if best_acc < test_acc and model_save is not None:
                best_acc = test_acc
                model.save(model_save)
            test_history['accruacy'].append(test_acc)
            test_history['loss'].append(test_loss)
            print(f'Epoch {ep*50}, Test Accuracy: {test_acc:.3f}, Test Loss: {test_loss:.3f}')
        print(f'Training Done. History : {history.history}')

the model is :
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras import layers

"""
I make three model and then totlly I use each models and get multimodal_output"""

class RESblock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel=3, stride=1,  map = False, map2 = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv1D(filters = filters, kernel_size = kernel, strides = stride, padding ='same')
        if stride == 2:
            stride = 1
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv1D(filters = filters, kernel_size = kernel, strides = stride, padding ='same')

        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = layers.LeakyReLU()
        self.iden = map
        self.filters = filters
        self.map2 = map2

    def build(self, input_shape):
        if self.iden is  True:
            self.match_channels = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(self.filters, 1, strides=2, padding='same')
        if self.map2 is True:
            self.match_channels = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(self.filters, 1, strides=1, padding='same')
            



    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training = training)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn(x, training = training)
        if self.iden or self.map2 is True:
            identity = self.match_channels(inputs)
            x = self.relu(x + identity)
        else :
            x = self.relu(x + inputs)
        x = tf.nn.max_pool1d(x,ksize=2, strides=2, padding='SAME')
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, 0.1)
        return x


class CNNBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = layers.Conv1D(filters = filters, kernel_size = kernel_size, strides = stride, padding ='same' )
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = layers.LeakyReLU()

    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x, training = training)
        x = self.relu(x)

        return x



class airflow_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = CNNBlock(16, 3, 1)
        self.res1 = RESblock(32, 3, 1, map2 = True)
        self.res2 = RESblock(64, 3, 1, map2 = True)

    

    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.res1(x, training = training)
        x = self.res2(x, training = training)

        return x
    
    def model(self, time_step):
        x = keras.Input(shape = ( time_step,1))
        return keras.Model(inputs = x, outputs = self.call(x))

    

class emg_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = CNNBlock(16, 3, 2)
        self.res1 = RESblock(16, 3, 2, map = True)
        self.res2_0 = RESblock(32, 3, 2, map = True)
        self.res3_0 = RESblock(64, 3, 2,  map = True)
    

    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.res1(x, training = training)
        x = self.res2_0(x, training = training)
        x = self.res3_0(x, training = training)

        return x
    
    def model(self, time_step):
        x = keras.Input(shape = ( time_step,1))
        return keras.Model(inputs = x, outputs = self.call(x))
    

class ecg_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = CNNBlock(16, 3, 1)
        self.res1 = RESblock(16, 3, 1)
        self.res2_0 = RESblock(32, 3, 2, map = True)
        self.res2  = RESblock(32, 3, 2, map = True)
        self.res3_0 = RESblock(64, 3, 2,  map = True)
        

    

    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.res1(x, training = training)
        x = self.res2_0(x, training = training)
        x = self.res2(x, training = training)
        x = self.res3_0(x, training = training)

        return x
    
    def model(self, time_step):
        x = keras.Input(shape = ( time_step,1))
        return keras.Model(inputs = x, outputs = self.call(x))
    
    
    
class multimodal_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ecg = ecg_model()
        self.emg = emg_model()
        self.airflow = airflow_model()
        self.lstm1 = layers.LSTM(64,  activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',return_sequences = True)
        self.lstm2 = layers.LSTM(32)
        self.dense = layers.Dense(1)
    
    def call(self, inputs, training = False):
        ecg, emg, airflow = inputs
        ecg_output = self.ecg(ecg, training = training)
        emg_output = self.emg(emg, training = training)
        airflow_output = self.airflow(airflow, training = training)
        print(f"ECG output shape: {ecg_output.shape}")
        print(f"EMG output shape: {emg_output.shape}")
        print(f"Airflow output shape: {airflow_output.shape}")
        
        combined_output = tf.concat([ecg_output, emg_output, airflow_output], axis = -2)
        print(f"Combined output shape after concat: {combined_output.shape}")
        print(combined_output.shape)
        x = self.lstm1(combined_output)
        x = self.lstm2(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x
    


model= multimodal_model()

